# Why is maven-surefire-plugin compulsory when using JUnit 5 in a Maven project?

Tags: maven, junit, junit5

I have used `JUnit` 3 and 4 for a long time in *maven* projects without `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Currently I started to try JUnit 5 by using the annotation from the JUnit Jupiter package `org.junit.jupiter.api`. Especially `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` is used instead of the legacy `org.junit.Test`. Eventually, No tests were detected and thus the testing failed.

The `maven-surefire-plugin` has to be added to `pom.xml` as such:
```

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

So Hereby I would like to ask:

- why is it compulsory to use `maven-surefire-plugin` with JUnit5 but not JUnit4 or JUnit3?
- is there workaround for using JUnit 5 without `maven-surefire-plugin`?

It is my habit to make the code as simple as possible

Comment: My assumption is you have used maven-surefire-plugin but not explicitly defined it...Now you have define it explicitly...Apart from that the include configuration in maven-surefire-plugin is not neccessary, cause it's the default...currently the support for JUnit5 in maven-surefire-plugin is not finished yet....

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your comment about the default configuration :) I tried on base of your comment to remove the `configuration` element, and it still worked. So the key is the `dependencies` inside the `maven-surefire-plugin`

Comment: @khmarbaise But I still would like to wait to get more comprehensive answers :)

Comment: As I said the Junit5 support in maven-surefire-plugin is not yet finished and needs a new release of maven-surefire-plugin which is currently being worked on...see the maven dev list...

Comment: @khmarbaise If so you can add a formal answer to your question and I will vote it right. Then you earn some points as reward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junit5 support in maven-surefire-plugin is not yet finished and needs a new release of maven-surefire-plugin which is [currently being worked on](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SUREFIRE?selectedItem=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:release-page)